# Configuring multi store backend of Magento 2

Tags: apache, .htaccess, localhost, magento2

So this is the problem I'm having.

1) I created the website, store and store view.

2) In the index.php file I have put the following code:

```
$params = $_SERVER;
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'test';
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

Question: do I add the store code to the domain name (e.g. test.exampledomain.com) or just add the store code like above?

3) In my htaccess file under the section

`## enable rewrites
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on`

I've put the following code:

```
SetEnvIf Host .*http://localhost/magento2.* MAGE_RUN_CODE=test
SetEnvIf Host .*http://localhost/magento2.* MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
```

4) I've tried this with domain names on a live site and on a dev localhost but can't seem too get the second store/site to show up I keep getting a 500 error. Is there something else I need to add or change?

like Vhost?

Can some explain what I'm doing wrong, I have gone through endless blogs and tutorials and still can get it to work.

In magento 1, you simply make the changes to the index.php file and the stores work with the set domains.

Answer (score 0):

I only changed the .htaccess file. 
Under RewriteEngineOn I added:
SetEnvIf Host .*[code].*  MAGE_RUN_CODE=[code]
SetEnvIf Host .*[code].*  MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website

That worked for me. 
So I see, you put the url for the store twice. Instead, put 'test' there, if that is the code_name you gave it in admin.

Answer (score 0):

You said "multistore" so I expected to see two stores.  You've set up only one in your index.php. Each store requires an entry like the one you have.  In other words, you need code like this:

```html
/* Code below is needed for multi store using different domains  */
switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
    case 'domain1.com':
        $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = '1';
        $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
        break;

    case 'domain2.com':
        $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = '2';
        $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
        break;
        }
```

And if you are not using subdomains for your stores, then

```html
  

/* Code below is needed for multi store using subdomains */
switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
    case 'sub1.domain1.com':
        $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = '1';
        $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
        break;

    case 'sub2.domain1.com':
        $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = '2';
        $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
        break;
        }
```

The number "1" and "2" refer to the store numbers in the Magento Admin and in the "store" database.